# Django datetime format with template filter

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-filter, templatetags

Hi I have a template tag/filter which converts a unix time to datetime. The following is the code I have:

```
@register.filter("timestamp")
def timestamp(value):
    if value is not None:
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(float(value))
    else:
        return 'None'
```

But it returns the date as `June 1, 2015, 3:06 p.m.`
How can I change the code, so that it returns me a 24hr formatted time? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really want to use custom filter for this ? You can use Django Builtins to display the result `June 1, 2015, 15`.

Comment: @blackwindow, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can change `settings.DATE_FORMAT`, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format

Or you can make your filter return a custom formatted string instead of a `datetime` object, e.g. using `datetime.strftime()`, https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime

> How can I change the code, so that it returns me a 24hr formatted
>   time?

The `%H` directive does the 24h format,

```
%H  Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior